# In unity, objects appear very soft on the scene but the game scene is completely pixelated

Tags: unity-game-engine, pixel

In unity, objects appear very soft on the scene but the game scene is completely pixelated.What is the problem?

[image: Screen]

[image: GameScreen]
[image: Canvas]
[image: Camera]
[image: Sprite]

Comment: Give some more information on what kind of object is that, Image UI, Sprite? What are your Camera settings, your Canvas and etc. It's hard to tell anything with so little information.
Learn to describe your issues as detailed as you can if you want to get help.

Comment: @hardartcore okay im added

Comment: Change your scale in Game View to 0. Currently it's set to 6.3x

Comment: @hardartcore I think the minimum is `1` ;) but yeah that's exactly the "issue" and would have been my first guess .... just **never** zoom on the GameView

Answer (score 0):

Your game view scale is set to 6.3x (zoomed in). Change it to 1x.

Answer (score 0):

[Image is zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy7h6.png)

Your gameview is fully zoomed. Zoom out and everything will be fine.